# Mapping Stored Procedures as Entity methods instead of Context methods

Tags: entity-framework

I am looking for a way to map stored procedures logically related to a table as functions within the Entity generated for that specific table instead of function in overall Context.

As an example, I have generated edmx out of existing bank database and I got a Context and several entities corresponding to the tables. Assume we have tables for Account, Transactions, Address, etc... and I have a stored proc returning current balance for the account. I want to map this stored proc to the Account entity instead of the context. This will help me to call Account.GetBalance() instead of Context.GetBalance().

Is this possible in entity framework ? I did lot of search and read few articles/blogs in msdn but couldn't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible unless you manually wrap the method exposed on context in your entity - that would make your entities persistence aware and EF dependent which is currently considered as exact opposite of design people should follow.

In terms of EF balance should be property of account entity and retrieving balance should mean reloading account or executing projection query (or your procedure) on accounts set / context. Queries are executed from context and stored procedures as well.